# Internet connectivity issue in Android App even after net connected

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-volley, android-internet

I have an app which "sometimes" doesn't connects to the internet. My app fetches JSON data from Volley and also Firebase valueEventListeners that fires up on app launch. Even after being connected to the internet, my app sometimes doesn't fetch data either from Volley or Firebase, but in reality, my internet speed is 60mb/s and WhatsApp and all works fine. So, it's definitely my app issue. I have a method in my app for Detecting network connection. So, if not connected, it displays a Toast message. But I ain't even getting a Toast message(not connected state). Once Volley fetches data, I've got a progress bar which disappears. But sometimes, it just keeps animating!

Can this be an app issue or can some third party libs create such issue? I do have many libraries in my app like Volley, Fancy Snackbar library, Dialogs and many more.

Comment: Please check if the url you are pointing to gets connected on call. Sometimes even if connectivity signal is shown your url may not be reachable.

Comment: This is definitely an app issue.If you could share your code and explain about your app,then i could tell you the main cause of it.Tip:Try using logs when you fetch data from json using volley and see the results.

Comment: @PoojaRajendranC Firebase should work in that case, but that ain't too!